# Creating a CloudSQL instance with terraform and custom tier

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

#### Problem:

I want to be able to granularly create/modify a PostgreSQL CloudSQL instance in Google Cloud Platform with Terraform.
Currently there is a setting `tier = "<instance_type>"`

#### Example:

Taken from Terraform documentation

```
  name             = "master-instance"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_11"
  region           = "us-central1"

  settings {
    # Second-generation instance tiers are based on the machine
    # type. See argument reference below.
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
  }
}
```

#### Summary:

How Can I modify this to match what I have now? Can I create a custom image to use in GCP?

I see there is a way to make a custom image [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type#create), but how would I use it in Terraform?

[Current settings in CloudSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gVfQ.png)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The instance tier is the machine [type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#tier) and and for custom machine types you can set the values in that variable like this: `db-custom-<CPUs>-<Memory_in_MB>` so for example in your case would be:

```
  name             = "master-instance"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_11"
  region           = "us-central1"

  settings {
    # Second-generation instance tiers are based on the machine
    # type. See argument reference below.
    tier = "db-custom-12-61440"
  }
}
```

I replicated it on  my project and with this values I was able to create an instance with 12 CPUs and 60 GB memory